# Этимология слова "стреха"

Tags: этимология

Как произошло слово "стр**е**ха"? Является ли оно исконно славянским и всегда ли значило то, что значит сейчас?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этимологическом словаре А.К. Шапошникова находим:

> Стреха – нижний свисающий край крыши. ▲ В рус. языке XI–XVII вв. изв.
>   «выступ кровли», стреха отм. в словаре 1794 г., стреха – с 1822
>   г. ▲ Из праслав. *стрěха, соотносительного с *стропъ «кровля,
>   перекрытие» и производного с суф. -х- от основы *стрě-, восходящей (по
>   мнению некоторых) к и.-е. глаг. *k’re-: *k’rē-: *k’ro-: *k’rō-
>   «нависать, навесить» (с вставным -т- между -с- и -р-), или к глаг.
>   *ster-: *stor-: *str- «расширять, простирать, распространять» (так как кровля простирается шире периметра стен).